# Dúvida sobre funções definidas dentro de constantes

Tags: javascript

Execute:

```js
function ok(n) {
  return console.log(n + 2);
}

console.log('porque o resultado da expressão abaixo trás o valor "NaN"?');
console.log('const minhaConstEumaFuncao = ok(), result: ')

const minhaConstEumaFuncao = ok()


console.log('enquanto que se eu der um log na minha constant "minhaConstEumaFuncao" o valor que resulta é: ', minhaConstEumaFuncao)

console.log('Enquanto que se eu der um typeof(minhaConstEumaFuncao) aparece: ', typeof(minhaConstEumaFuncao));
```

Porque o typeof da constante que guarda uma função é undefined enquanto que o log da constante de uma função traz NaN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos uma pergunta por vez.

> porque o resultado da expressão abaixo trás o valor "NaN"?

a função "ok" espera um parâmetro n e você não está passando parâmetro algum, quando não passa um parâmetro para a função ele fica como `undefined`, dentro da função você tenta somar undefined com 2, que gera um NaN (not a number).

Para resolver isso basta você passar um parametro para a função assim:

```
ok(2)
```

Assim ele irá trazer o valor 4 :)

> enquanto que se eu der um log na minha constant "minhaConstEumaFuncao" o valor que resulta é:  undefined

você está armazenando o valor do retorno da função para a constante porém a função não retorna nada! então a constante tem valor `undefined` também.

> Enquanto que se eu der um typeof(minhaConstEumaFuncao) aparece:  undefined

typeof de undefined é undefined

Answer (score 1):

Porque o `console.log` não retorna um valor.

Se você fizer algo do tipo

```
var val = console.log(2 + 2);
console.log(val);
```

Você vai perceber que `val` possui o valor `undefined`. Isso é porque o `console.log` não retorna o valor que ele imprime. Então na sua função se você quiser retornar o mesmo valor que é imprimido pelo `console`, você deveria fazer algo do tipo

```
function ok(n) {
  var resultado = n + 2;
  console.log(resultado);
  return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Mas o que explicaria o typeof "variavel" ser undefined então?

Comment: Uma variável não inicializada tem o valor `undefined` em JS. O valor de `minhaConstEumaFuncao` é `undefined`, e o tipo de um valor `undefined` é `"undefined"`.